# Groovy MockFor - how to handle calls to "with" methods on mocks

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, mocking

I faced with interesting problem while using mocking support in Groovy to test collaboration with dependency. We have two classes (example):

```
class Dependency {

    void method() {
        throw new OperationNotSupportedException()
    }
}

class Dependent {

    Dependency dependency

    void useDependency() {
        dependency.with {  method() }
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the way how method() being called on dependency - it's done inside "with" method of dependency.

I need to mock call to method() in test so my first attempt was to do something like this:

```
class IgnoringWithTest {

    @Test
    void testWithMock() {
        def depMock = new MockFor(Dependency)
        Dependent dep = new Dependent()
        depMock.demand.method { }
        dep.dependency = depMock.proxyInstance()

        dep.useDependency()

        depMock.verify dep.dependency
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this "naive" approach lead to error message during test execution "No call to 'with' expected at this point. Still 1 call(s) to 'method' expected." It's fine as we really try to call with() method on dependency here.

I tried to ignore call to with() method by adding next line:

```
depMock.ignore('with')
```

After this I didn't receive complains about with() method calls however it turned out that expectation declared using demand was ignored. As a result I got OperationNotSupportedException.

And now is the question - how to make mock for method() without having problems when in implementation it will be called in closure passed to with()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug with MockFor, but there is an easy workaround:  enclose the use of the mock within a `depMock.use` block like so:

```
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor

class IgnoringWithTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testWithMock() {
        def depMock = new MockFor(Dependency)
        Dependent dep = new Dependent()
        depMock.ignore('with')
        depMock.demand.method { }
        dep.dependency = depMock.proxyInstance()

        depMock.use {
            dep.useDependency()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why but using 'use' block works in this case. I would assume that this is some Groovy bug as well.